# TypeScript losing type information after spread?

Tags: typescript

In the following code, why does the `personInvalidAndErrorCaught` assignment give a TypeScript error (as I would expect) but the `personInvalidButErrorUncaught` does not? Especially since both lines transpile to the same JavaScript?

**TypeScript:**

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}
const person: Person = { name: "name" }
const personInvalidAndErrorCaught: Person = { ...person, invalidKey: ""  } // Error as expected: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'invalidKey' does not exist in type 'Person'.(2322)
const personInvalidButErrorUncaught: Person = { ...person, ...{ invalidKey: "" } } // Why no error? Especially since this line transpiles to the same JS as the line above?
```

**Transpiled JavaScript:**

```
"use strict";
const person = { name: "name" };
const personInvalidButCaught = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, person), { invalidKey: "" }); 
const personInvalidButUncaught = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, person), { invalidKey: "" });
```

**Image showing error:**

[image: Screenshot of playground showing error]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EI53IAOmOGuijZcAXnykK1ZACIylWcg5cQPfiJwBJEADc4AG2AATAEIBXMAGE45xgAswQgeMkA6DxtEAaZKH1GxgDSEACeNLJKysgA9DHIAKJQUFhQyHAYyBAAHvwIkMY0APIARgBWEPnIRpBQhsjkcKHIOAbNGHnAMM0A1iBYAO64vCkaYMAQGL5wIMbIAOT+hiYhofPIxliTpFhgWdnAPKDIYKH8C8Ki824AFABMAMx3dwCUnNx7Xtp6y2aWAKogBC2BxONAuZASPDIDxuL4gXyw6FLQKrCJKNjROLIADq9ma-SyyVSAH5Eh1KsBDG1aKAkMgSrt7Cc6iBeMADCgwFgTvYUBhpMgAFIAZXeaiwnLcBiwjBu8J0ARMFmsIMcvgVP0CKsBwLsjhezCAA)

Comment: Thanks @ford04, yes that answered my question. Your comment and the accepted answer both lead me to learn about [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you're directly assigning the object literal containing the invalid key in the case that doesn't work, and TypeScript treats that specially. From the [beta documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) *(they warn that link may rot)*:

> Notice the given argument to `createSquare` is spelled `colour` instead of `color`. In plain JavaScript, this sort of thing fails silently.
>
> You could argue that this program is correctly typed, since the `width` properties are compatible, there’s no `color` property present, and the extra `colour` property is insignificant.
>
> However, TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code. **Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables**, or passing them as arguments.

*(my emphasis)*

(There's also the [current documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) you found.)

In your second case where there's no error, you're not assigning the object literal with the excess property to the variable directly, you're assigning the wrapper object that it gets spread into. It's a subtle distinction, granted, but it's a distinction.

This is just a special case TypeScript flags up because when you're assigning the literal directly and specifying an invalid property, that's likely to be a bug. Something more complex may not be.

The fact that spreading doesn't trigger this check is, as you found in [one of the tests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/98a688f20defba33036348dfddb383b3fe4f5e70/tests/baselines/reference/spreadExcessProperty.js#L4), by design:

> ```
> const a1: A = { ...extra1 }; // spread should not give excess property errors
> ```

Comment: Thanks, now that I've learnt about [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) I've found the following [test](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/98a688f20defba33036348dfddb383b3fe4f5e70/tests/baselines/reference/spreadExcessProperty.js#L4) that verifies this is by design: `const a1: A = { ...extra1 }; // spread should not give excess property errors`

Comment: @HeinrichFilter Oooooh, nice finds!